# Excel VBA OR Formula

Tags: excel

I am wanting to set up a macro or formula to automatically remove duplicates in a column. Column c is where the data is inputted, this then populates in column a but column A needs to contain none of the duplicates. My column B is checking A against C to see how many times A criteria's appear in B and this all feeds through to my front end sheet.

So like i say, A needs to populate with C data but remove duplicates in A at the same time.

Many thanks for any help

Comment: Welcome to SO matt t! You're much more likely to receive help if you make an attempt and include your code in your question. SO is a Q&A site for specific coding problems, not a code writing service.

Comment: Have you tried the built in function `Data -> Data Tools -> Remove Duplicates`?